# I am unable to install wordcloud on vscode

Tags: python

I was working with sentiment analysis today, and when i started importing libraries i am unable to install wordcloud. it gives me an error as follows when i try to install **pip install wordcloud**. i also tried to install it by downloading it and copying it to my current directory and **python -m pip install wordcloud-1.8.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl** but that does not work too.

i.e. i am using windows, vscode and python3.9

The log error is

PS E:\projects\python\sentiment> **pip install wordcloud**

Collecting wordcloud
Using cached wordcloud-1.8.1.tar.gz (220 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.16.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for wordcloud, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
Running setup.py install for wordcloud ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ij5wisei\wordcloud_65d6145d63024c6693ae2f4a8a7fb0a8\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ij5wisei\wordcloud_65d6145d63024c6693ae2f4a8a7fb0a8\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ppnm2m4u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\wordcloud'
cwd: C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ij5wisei\wordcloud_65d6145d63024c6693ae2f4a8a7fb0a8
Complete output (20 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud\color_from_image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud\tokenization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud\wordcloud.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud\wordcloud_cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud_*main*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud\stopwords -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
copying wordcloud\DroidSansMono.ttf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud
UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud/_version.py
set build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\wordcloud/_version.py to '1.8.1'
running build_ext
building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ij5wisei\wordcloud_65d6145d63024c6693ae2f4a8a7fb0a8\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ij5wisei\wordcloud_65d6145d63024c6693ae2f4a8a7fb0a8\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ppnm2m4u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\robel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\wordcloud' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Do you gave Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater installed? Is it on your PATH?

Answer (score 2):

Try installed worcloud by **.whl** file.

Choose the version that suit for you. [Wordcloud.whl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud)

Use cmd and type this command:

step 1

```
cd *your file directory path*
```

step 2

```
pip install *the file name.whl*
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that wordcloud has no prebuilt wheels for python3.9 on windows. Therefore when you install it it will download the source code and try to build the wheel.
In order to successfully build this wheel you need a c compiler.

As the error suggests you can download [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).

After downloading and installing (make sure you have the correct version between 32 and 64 bit depending on your python architecture) then retry doing `pip install wordcloud`

Comment: It is way forward I agree, but after installing Build Tools pip install still throws errors.
There are some articles on the internet to fix those but after playing with it for like 2 hours I gave and installed from downloaded [wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud)
For python 3.9 I have used this command:
`python -m pip install wordcloud-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 1):

The comment made by @Wojciech Jakubas is what worked for me.

1. Download the **wordcloud‑1.8.1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl** file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud)
   (Note that the *cp39* in the filename reflects the python version YOU are using, so make sure you download the compatible file. e.g. here cp39 means python 3.9)
2. Open the command prompt in the directory where the downloaded file is located. Or just ***cd*** your way there.
3. Run this command `python -m pip install wordcloud-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`
   (again make sure to use the specific filename of the file that you download as that may vary depending on what python version you're downloading your file for)

I'm making this comment, for one because my reputation is too low to reply others and second because this answer sort of makes the steps involved explicit for accessibility's sake.